# Compare 2 Strings in Excel and return the remainder

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I would like to subtract certain words from a title and output the remainder.

Is there a formula or macro that would accomplish this task?

Thank you for any assistance.

**Main Title:**
Apple Inc Iphone 7 Case

**Subtract These Words:**
Apple Iphone 7

**Ouput Remainder:**
Inc Case

Comment: What have you tried?  Unless you have Office 365 Excel with access to TEXTJOIN(), you will need vba.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "Find and Replace" functionality in Excel.  That could do the trick:

```
Ctrl+H
```

This pulls up a menu where you can replace specific instances or all instances of strings of words within formulae with something else (or nothing at all).

Comment: OP would need to do at least two find replaces to make it work as the three words do not appear in the same order.

Comment: That is a good point.  TEXTJOIN is much simpler, I agree with you.  I was offering a solution in case OP did not have a newer version of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

As stated if one has TEXTJOIN() then this array formula will do it:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),999 * (ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1)+1,999)),B1)),"",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),999 * (ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1)+1,999))))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

---

If you do not have TEXTJOIN() native, put this code in a module attached to the workbook and use the formula exactly as described above.

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```